# How can I use a variable name with nodejs tool on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I'm using Jenkins pipeline but since the last update it fails during `tools` with: "ERROR: No jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation named 12.5.0".

This is for Jenkins 2.183 and NodeJS-Plugin 1.33

```
// When using a constant string, it works.
pipeline {
  agent any
  environment {
    NODEJS_VERSION = readFile '.nvmrc'
  }
  tools {
    nodejs "12.5.0"
  }
  ...
}

// When using a variable as the nodejs name, it fails.
// "ERROR: No jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation named 12.5.0"
pipeline {
  agent any
  environment {
    NODEJS_VERSION = readFile '.nvmrc'
  }
  tools {
    nodejs env.NODEJS_VERSION
  }
  ...
}
```

I expect that when using a variable it should work the same way as using a constant string. Also, it seems that the variable name is recognized (as shown in the error).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `.nvmrc` had an extra linebrak

```
12.5.0
```

Replacing the Jenkinsfile with the code below solved the problem.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  environment {
    NODEJS_VERSION = "${readFile '.nvmrc'}".trim()
  }
  tools {
    nodejs env.NODEJS_VERSION
  }
  ...
}
```